# MySQL: Create new column if doesn't exist and copy the values of already existing column to newly created column in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-python

We are doing a mini project using Flask and want to add this feature in UI as well as in mysql :
We have the table name students. So the below table data displayed will be show in UI as it is and the same data stored in mysql too.

```
srno  name   branch

1     harry  CSE
2     Jay    Mech
3     Jane   ECE
```

srno is the primary key. But, we have decided to add a unique registration number to all the students by appending random letters(2 or 3) to srno. For example: 1ab, 2cd, 3yt like this.
We fetching data from sql table and passing it to static files(below myresult will be passed)

```
 mycursor.execute(query)
 myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Without manually writing unique registration number for every column we want to do recursively(if possible, by writing python code) by adding new column to it and at a same time add those unique values by appending random characters to srno to the newly created column.

and final result will be

```
srno  name   branch  regno

1     harry  CSE     1ab
2     Jay    Mech    2dc
3     Jane   ECE     3ef
```

We have tried so many ways, but failed achieving it. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3 digit unique id? have you tried adding a new column using alter table? and also you can write a custom insert function to add unique regno using `uuid` python lib

Comment: Could you show the many ways you tried so we could try to fix them?